# ¿Cómo obtengo la extensión de fichero de un InputStream en un servicio REST Java?

Tags: java, excel, rest, jersey

Tengo un servicio REST `Java` montado con `Jersey`.

Estoy utilizando la librería de `javax` para subir un fichero **.xlsx** al servidor. Antes de subir este fichero, me gustaría comprobar que la extensión es correcta, es decir, que es únicamente **.xlsx**.

He probado con lo siguiente, pero la variable mimeType viene `null`:

```
@POST
@Path("/update")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@ApiOperation(value = "Update excel", notes = "Uploads and updates an excel with food preferences", response = JSONObject.class)
public JsonResponse updateExcel(
@FormDataParam("foodExcel") InputStream foodExcel) {
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(foodExcel);
    String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is);
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo he solucionado yo misma. He inyectado mi parámetro foodExcel como **FormDataBodyPart** para poder recoger el mimeType y después lo he pasado a **InputStream** para poder trabajar con él.

```
@POST
@Path("/update")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@ApiOperation(value = "Update excel", notes = "Uploads and updates an excel with food preferences", response = JSONObject.class)
public JsonResponse updateExcel(
@FormDataParam("foodExcel") FormDataBodyPart foodExcel) {
    String mimeType = foodExcel.getMediaType().toString();
    InputStream is = foodExcel.getEntityAs(InputStream.class);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

TE sugiero usar MultipartFile para ello tal como esta en este ejemplo.

```
@PostMapping("/recursos/digital")
public  DescripcionSubidaArchivo agregarRecursoFisico(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    String nombreArchivo = almacenamiento.almacenarArchivo(file);

    String rutaArchivo = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
            .path("/Descarga/")
            .path(nombreArchivo)
            .toUriString();

    return new DescripcionSubidaArchivo(nombreArchivo,rutaArchivo, file.getContentType(), file.getSize());

}
```

Tambien puedes usar `ResponseEntity<Resource>`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero no ha sido necesario usar el Multipart, simplemente inyecté mi parámetro como FormDataBodyPart . Un saludo.